# WinXP: Can't login. Can't boot at all in safe mode

Tags: windows-xp, boot, safe-mode

On my WinXP Laptop I can boot normally to the Welcome Screen but when I try to login it makes the sound it usually does, the screen blinks, and I am back to the welcome screen again.

I tried to boot in safe mode but that does not work at all. It just fails with a bluescreen that I can't read because right after it appears on the screen the computer shuts down and reboots.

What can I do? Ideally I would like to go back to a restore point.

Comment: What is the last .sys file that safe mode loads before the blue screen? Also, are you tapping F8 to get the safe mode menu? If so, press enter on "Disable automatic restart on system failure".

Comment: if you can boot to a command prompt, run "rstrui" to start system-restore.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like bad RAM .  I would download [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) and check the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Right, first off, if you can, take your hard drive out, stick it into another machine and get a back up!

If you have more than 1 RAM chip, try just 1 chip, and then swap the chip to see if the problem persists.

If you have more than 1 hard drive, unplug it and try again (same with all external devices, include USB and your DVD/CD ROM).